# Error launching source instance: InvalidBlockDeviceMapping: Volume of size 8GB is smaller than snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terragrunt

I came across an issue while launching a single ec2 instance (with existing AMI having volume size=32GB) using the ec2-instance gruntwork module in terraform-aws-service-catalog. It does not allow the creation of root volume with the given snapshot id (size=32GB). The error popped up while launching ec2 instance -

```
module.demo_instance.module.ec2_instance.aws_instance.instance: Creating...
Error: Error launching source instance: InvalidBlockDeviceMapping: Volume of size 8GB is smaller than  snapshot 'snap-0850762dcfacpb2957', expect size >= 32GBB
  on .terraform/modules/demo_instance.ec2_instance/modules/single-server/main.tf line 23, in resource "aws_instance" "instance":
  23: resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
```

I see ec2 instance is using single-server module from terraform-aws-server and it has a default root_volume_size of 8GB which can't be modifiable from the ec2-instance module. And it seems that the ebs_volume I am trying to attach to ec2 instance is not working

```
module "demo_instance" {
      source = "git::git@github.com:gruntwork-io/terraform-aws-service-catalog.git//modules/services/ec2-instance?ref=v0.44.5"
    
      name          = "${var.name}-${var.account_name}"
      instance_type = var.instance_type
    
      ami = "ami-03a0a2de6ce3aq7ff7"
      
      ami_filters = null
    
    
      enable_ssh_grunt = false
      keypair_name     = local.key_pair_name
    
      vpc_id    = var.vpc_id
      subnet_id = var.subnet_ids[0]
      
    
      ebs_volumes = {
        "demo-volume" = {
          type        = "gp2"
          size        = 32
          snapshot_id = "snap-0850762dcfacpb2957"    
        },
      }
      
      allow_ssh_from_cidr_blocks = var.allow_ssh_from_cidr_list
    
      allow_ssh_from_security_group_ids  = []
      allow_port_from_cidr_blocks        = {}
      allow_port_from_security_group_ids = {}
    
      route53_zone_id            = ""
      dns_zone_is_private        = true
      route53_lookup_domain_name = ""
    }
```

Is there any way to modify the default value (8GB) of root_volume_size using ec2-instance gruntwork module ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a complete code to show? The few lines you showed are without any context.

Comment: @Marcin updated the question with code.

Comment: Does this module still exist? `github.com/gruntwork-io/terraform-aws-service-catalog.git` returns 404.

Comment: Yes, it exists for subscription-based users. It's not public @Marcin

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about an issue with proprietary code and not a general purpose question that anyone can weigh in on.

Answer (score 1):

Gruntwork raised an [issue](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terraform-aws-service-catalog/issues/760) regarding the problem. size is not exposed in the ec2-instance module. In the meantime, [single-server](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terraform-aws-server/blob/master/modules/single-server) module can be used directly.